# Selecting data structure to store words and look up their occurance?

Tags: list, data-structures, dictionary

Let's say I'm given a document with a bunch of words(a poem, for example). I'd then like to be able to store each word so that I can run a command such as: "ocean 4" to find where the fourth occurrence of the word "ocean" is within my text. What would be the best data structure to store this in?

I'd like to stay under O(n^2) but I think the solutions I've come up with so far are too inefficient.

Any help getting started would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can use a histogram or a hash map or a syntax tree. However, if you'd like to do it under O(n^2) you can just store it as a string and run indexOf 4 times which is O(n)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a hashtable where each word is the key, and then use a list. Each position within the list would store the location of the word within your text. for example in python you would call myDict["ocean"][4].